# General vs field specific journals in mathematics

Tags: mathematics, journals

What are the pros and cons of submitting a math paper to a general journal vs a field specific journal?

There are so many general journals today,
and sometimes there reputation is not nessecerily better than a journal devoted to a specific subfield.

Given that, is there any reason to prefer a generalist journal over a field specific one?

Comment: Can the downvoter explain the problem with the question?

Comment: @GJ: There is no problem with the question.  The ease of providing negative feedback is built into the SE site mechanics.  In many cases (as here) it's probably best to just ignore such feedback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to disentangle this issue from prestige, since many of the most prestigious journals in mathematics are general.

At the very top of the prestige scale (Annals and a handful of competitors), there are no specialized journals at all.  Specialized journals start to appear a little lower on the scale, and they become more common as one descends further, as well as more specialized.

To a first approximation, prestige is the more important factor.  For example, given a choice between GAFA and Transactions of the AMS, GAFA wins on prestige despite being quite a bit more specialized.  There may be other reasons you might prefer the Transactions (for example, the publisher's policies, or a desire to support the AMS), but if building an impressive CV is your primary motivation, you should go for prestige.

On the other hand, going with the broader journal is a good heuristic if you aren't sure which is more prestigious or don't think there's a big difference, since it's correlated with prestige and therefore tends to give a good impression.

Towards the bottom of the prestige pyramid, people may raise an eyebrow at overly specialized journals, since a paper acceptance doesn't mean much if it's in a venue specifically designed to ensure that specialized papers not easily publishable elsewhere find a home.  Of course that doesn't mean the papers are bad, but they won't look impressive on a CV.

Answer (score 4):

In the bigger picture, (for applying to future jobs, etc.), if you have articles that appear in journals that are more general, this looks very good; this shows that that your research has a wide appeal, rather than only being of interest to people only in a small niche subfield.

Of course, journals that are more focused can still be very good, and often can have good impact factors.  But I know that in mathematics, having all of my publications in focused journals would not be ideal; I would want to have a few in journals with a broader appeal.

(For example my field is finite geometry, which is very narrow; focused journals often include coding theory and design theory.  Journals on combinatorics are much more broad; publishing here shows that anyone who studies combinatorics might find my work interesting.  A publication in a completely general mathematics journal would show that any mathematician might find value in my work.)

Comment: I think this is a good rule of thumb, but I also think that generalist journals are essentially dense in the spectrum of journal quality.  I would say that it is easier for a generalist journal to be outright bad than a specialist journal: a generalist journal can be bad just by having plausible deniability about the interest of most of its papers.

Comment: E.g. a bad generalist journal can get a paper on design theory, and through some combination of ignorance, predatory malice or simply not trying hard enough, could send it to a referee that knows nothing about design theory.  (Lest you think this is implausible, let me say that I have been the referee in essentially isomorphic situations: e.g. not design theory but control theory.)  I think it is hard for a journal specializing in design theory to be this bad, because the badness would be much more evident.